# How to dismiss Keypad on iOS after UIButton is pressed using Swift

Tags: swift

I want to dismiss the Keypad on iOS after a UIButton is pressed, I am not sure what to put into the function to dismiss the keypad.

```
 @IBAction func calculateWagesButton(sender : UIButton) {

       //Magic Code Here....?? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing swift specific here.

Just grab the first responder and make it resign. For instance, if it's a textfield:

```
self.textfield.resignFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 3):

1st Step :- implement `UITextFieldDelegate` like:

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

2nd Step :- In viewDidLoad function wrtie following line:

```
self.textfield.delegate = self
```

3rd Step :- use following method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true;
}
```

I hope, these code helps you . . .